# How to store user conversation data with bot into azure SQL database using C# langugage?

Tags: azure-sql-database, bots, botframework

I am currently working on Bot framework technology, in my current project I want to store the bot conversation data into azure SQL database.

I have developed one ReviewBot, In this I have to write the code for to give review/rating of any hotel by user.

Bot communicate with user is working fine but I want to store the user conversation data with my bot into azure SQL database using C# language.

Please tell me how to implement the above concept.

Regards,
Pradeep

Comment: What conversation data do you need to save? The entire conversation?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you looking to store the bot data (i.e. the user, conversation, and private conversation property bags) in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a tutorial showing this: [Implementing A SQL Server Database With The Microsoft Bot Framework](http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/13/Implementing-A-SQL-Server-Database-With-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework)

The key piece of code is:

```
// *************************
// Log to Database
// *************************

// Instantiate the BotData dbContext
Models.BotDataEntities DB = new Models.BotDataEntities();
// Create a new UserLog object
Models.UserLog NewUserLog = new Models.UserLog();
// Set the properties on the UserLog object
NewUserLog.Channel = activity.ChannelId;
NewUserLog.UserID = activity.From.Id;
NewUserLog.UserName = activity.From.Name;
NewUserLog.created = DateTime.UtcNow;
NewUserLog.Message = activity.Text;

// Add the UserLog object to UserLogs
DB.UserLogs.Add(NewUserLog);
// Save the changes to the database
DB.SaveChanges();
```