# How I create a chatbot which reads and writes to a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, botframework

I am new to MS bot framework and working on my project. I wanted to create a chatbot that can read from the database (I am using SQL Server for creating database) and also takes data from the users and saves it in the database. I have searched a lot but I was not able to find any tutorial regarding this. Can anyone help me and kindly show it with code on how to do this ? Thanks.

Comment: This is an overly general question. You're basically asking someone to code the chatbot for you? Please ask specific questions.

Comment: I don't want anyone to code for me I am just asking for a general format or method on how to achieve this

Comment: Your google research must be way to specific if you cant find any tutorials. Just look for a starter on reading and writing to sql server using C#.

Comment: @TomC I really couldn't find any tutorial in which data from SQL server is read or written into the bot framework, I was very worried so thought to post the question to get any help

Comment: How is "data from SQL server is read or written into the bot framework" different from any other framework?

Comment: @Hafsah take a look at this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks I guess I just didn't ask my question the right way. I apologize for it :)

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851302/how-to-store-user-conversation-data-with-bot-into-azure-sql-database-using-c-sha

Answer (score 1):

The approach I use in my project for Bot and DB:

1. Build a Rest APIs for request information to the DB. For example you can build a project in ASP.NET and use Entity Framework. Then build your repository... and finally build your controller's endpoints (Example: CRUDs operation).
2. Then use your bot's logic for make request to the Rest APIs endpoints. For examble use the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)

Retrieve data from user:

Here you have a lot of options. Depending on what you need you can retrieve data using:

1. regular expression,
2. using Natural Language Processing (NLP) like LUIS.
3. Prompt user for data.[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-primitive-prompts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)
4. And more...

My best advice is to read the [Microsoft Botframework Documentation](https://dev.botframework.com/) to learn how bot work. For Web APIs, look for tutorials

Comment: But still I don't know what to do for example in my bot if I use Luis intents how it can read data from the database to reply to the. This is the actual problem.

Comment: For LUIS Services you can create a LUIS application on LUIS.ai. Then define an intent and use “entities” for extract data from user’s utterance.  The botframework provide tutorials on how to implement LUIS apps on bots. Also LUIS Documentation provide tutorial on how to create intent, entities, etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are two ways how you can create your Chat Bot:

1. Azure
2. Locally

**Azure Chat Bot:**

If you want something more than you have to create an Account on Azure and create a chat bot. Link this bot with Bot Framework and get going. You can visit this link to create an Azure Chat Bot: [Create Azure Chat Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). Also you will need to create an Azure SQL Database and its reference you can find here: [Create Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-database-get-started?tabs=azure-portal)

**Local Chat Bot using Bot Framework**
I have one good link for you. I am sure you will get your answer here. [Create Local Chat Bot using Bot Framework and save conversation in SQL Database](http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/13/Implementing-A-SQL-Server-Database-With-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework) .This guy has created an SQL Database and then connected this Database to the Bot Framework. For this you need to install the Bot Framework. This is the standard way how you can create a Chat Bot locally.

But this is not it. You need to search more on internet how to use your Chat Bot according to scenarios, because both the case that I discussed will create a default chat bot having some inbuilt chats.

If you want to integrate your LUIS with QnA Maker ( which is a Knowledge Base ) you can visit this link: [LUIS and QnAMaker - Bot Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/integrate-qnamaker-luis)

Hope this helps.